# Ruby: Dynamically creating function call arguments list from an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, axlsx

I'm creating a spreadsheet using the `axlsx` gem. I'd like to set fixed width to on all spreadsheet columns and I need to call the function

```
def column_widths(*widths)
  widths.each_with_index do |value, index|
    next if value == nil
    Axlsx::validate_unsigned_numeric(value) unless value == nil
    find_or_create_column_info(index).width = value
  end
end
```

defined in the `Axlsx::Worksheet` with an arbitrary number of column widths. E.g. `sheet.column_width(20, 20, ..., 20). My method call looks like

```
sheet.column_widths [20]*headers.length
```

and it result in the error

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Invalid Data [20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20] for Invalid column width. must be [Fixnum, Integer, Float].
```

How can I dynamically create a proper method call for the unknown number of columns?

Comment: What about `sheet.column_widths(*[20]*headers.length)` ?

Comment: That works. Thanks! Would you like to post an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the method `column_widths` is defined like this:

```
def column_widths(*widths)
  # some stuff
```

The splatter operator `*` present in the arguments `*widths` means that you can have from 1 to N (where N > 1) arguments. You are trying to use this method with an array of Integer, instead you should pass each Integer as single argument, something like:

```
sheet.column_widths(20, 20, 20, 20, #etc...
```

But this is not the best way to do it. One better way to use these arguments is to also use the splatter operator:

```
sheet.column_widths(*[20]*headers.length)
                   #^ This is the splatter operator
```

---

A very explicit example of the utility of the splatter operator (in my IRB console, Ruby 1.9.3p489):

```
ann, marc, john = *['Ann', 'Marc', 'John']
# => ["Ann", "Marc", "John"] 
ann
# => "Ann"
```

Some stuff about the splatter operator: http://4loc.wordpress.com/2009/01/16/the-splat-operator-in-ruby/

Comment: You could also `widths.flatten.each_with_index` to make the interface a little more flexible and DWIMy.